# Efficiently invoking GetByIds (MS Graph API method) when input record count > 1000 records

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm currently trying to integrated Azure AD to my existing ASP.NET app.
As a part of this, I'm also planning to leverage MS Graph.

To fetch the total Groups of which a given User is a part of directly/indirectly, I'm successfully able to invoke the GetMemberObjects() successfully as follows:

```
var lstMemberObj = graphServiceClient.Users[userName].GetMemberObjects(true).Request().PostAsync().Result.ToList();
```

Now to get each of the Group's respective names from the lstMemberObj output, I have to use GetByIds API (for which the input will lstMemberObj).
So I'm trying to invoke GetByIds () as follows:

```
var lstGroupById = graphServiceClient.DirectoryObjects.GetByIds(lstMemberObj , new string[] { "group" }).Request().PostAsync().Result.ToList();
```

But since the input limit for GetByIds cannot exceed 1000 records, this method fails when a User is part of more than 1000 records.

So I've currently tried pagination to traverse through lstMemberObj as follows:

```
                int pageSize = 1000;
                int totalCount = lstMemberObj != null && lstMemberObj .Any() ? lstMemberObj .Count():0;
                int page = 1;
                int skip = pageSize * (page - 1);
                List<string> lstMemberObj2 = new List<string>();
                List<DirectoryObject> lstGroupById2;
                List<DirectoryObject> finalLstGroupById = new List<DirectoryObject>();

                while (skip < totalCount)
                {                   
                    lstMemberObj2 = lstMemberObj.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();
                    lstGroupById2= graphServiceClient.DirectoryObjects.GetByIds(substituteGroupIDsList, new string[] { "group" }).Request().PostAsync().Result.ToList();
                    finalLstGroupById .AddRange(lstGroupById2);
                    page++;
                    skip = pageSize * (page - 1);
                }
```

Although with this logic I'm successfully able to fetch the desired output, is this logic efficient enough? Is there any default MS Graph parameters which I can use to handle this scenario for GetByIds method when input records > 1000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement, you can also do it by the code below:

```
var url = graphClient.Users["user email"].MemberOf.AppendSegmentToRequestUrl("microsoft.graph.group");
            
UserMemberOfCollectionWithReferencesRequestBuilder aabuild = new UserMemberOfCollectionWithReferencesRequestBuilder(url, graphClient);

var groups = await aabuild.Request().Top(1000).GetAsync();

List<string> nameList = new List<string>();
while (groups.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var group in groups) {
        var s = group.AdditionalData["displayName"];
        nameList.Add((string)s);
    }
        
    if (groups.NextPageRequest != null)
    {
        groups = await groups.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}

foreach (var name in nameList)
{
    //print display name of each group
    Console.WriteLine(name);
}
```

In my code, it request [this graph api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) in backend.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/memberOf/microsoft.graph.group
```